# How to collapse the rows in r

Tags: r

The dataset is as follows:

| DATE | ID | Value | Temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2000 | 1 | 1 | 21 |
| 01-01-2000 | 1 | 4 | 21 |
| 02-01-2000 | 2 | 9 | 34 |
| 02-01-2000 | 3 | 5 | 37 |
| 02-01-2000 | 3 | 4 | 37 |

I expect this outcome:

| DATE | ID | Value | Temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2000 | 1 | 5 | 21 |
| 02-01-2000 | 2 | 9 | 34 |
| 02-01-2000 | 3 | 9 | 37 |

I try to use aggregate but it cannot keep the variable - Temp

Please give me some suggestions, thank you

`aggregate(data$Value, by=list(Date=data$ID), FUN=sum)`

The above code only returned:

| DATE | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2000 | 5 |
| 02-01-2000 | 9 |
| 02-01-2000 | 9 |

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! sharing your code would help (makes your problem reproducible) Also! in your original dataset there is no ```ID 3, Value 9, Temp 37``` combination which does exist in your expected outcome

Comment: I mean sum the value variable with same id, date and temp

Comment: @user438383 I read the post and that post only related two variables, which can be solved by aggregate easily. However, I want to sum a specific column and also keep the other columns...

Comment: `aggregate(Value ~ DATE + ID + Temp, df, sum) `

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't reproducible but try this:

```
aggregate(Value~ID, DatasetName, sum)
```